# Can't update document in mongodb (want to push item in array)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

at first i apologize for my english :(
im new at **nodeJs** and **mongodb** and i have a problem
I can't add any item into array
This is what i tried:

```
db.conversations.update({userID: memberID} ,{
       "user_users" : {
           $push : { "member": userID } // this does not work :((
          }
         });
```

and i also tried this:

```
db.conversations.user_users = {
            $push : {
                 member: memberID
             }
            };
            db.conversations.save();
```

i want to work like this :

```
{
"_id" : conversationID,
"userID" : userID,
"user_users" : { "member" : memberID,  "member" : memberID }
}
```

Comment: possible duplication -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose?rq=1

Comment: `$push` only works for arrays. `user_users` in the document above is an object.

Comment: @brian-shamblen yes you are right but now how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following JSON :

```
{
    "_id": conversationID,
    "userID": userID,
    "user_users": {
        "member": memberID,
        "member": memberID
    }
}
```

is not valid, because "member" is a duplicated key. What you could do is to transform user_users to an array of users and do something like this :

```
{
    "_id": conversationID,
    "userID": userID,
    "user_users": [
        {
            "member": memberID
        },
        {
            "member": memberID
        }
    ]
}
```

where each member of the array user_users is a document. You would then be able to do the following query to add members to your array :

```
db.conversations.update(
    {userID: memberID} ,
    {$push : {"user_users" : { "member": userID }}}
)
```

Comment: really helps me ♥ tnx