# How to update a specific element inside a sub-document array using moongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using node.js and mongoose in my app.
I have one Schema and a sub-schema.

```
const childrenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  hobbies: [String]
})

const parentSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
   type: String, trim: true, required: true,
  },
  children: [childrenSchema],
})

const parent = mongoose.model('parent', parentSchema)
```

I want to change a specific child inside a parrent.
I've tried something like this:

```
const parentId = '1234'

const childToUpdate = {
  _id: '8765432',
  hobbies: ['guitar', 'javascript']
}

Parent.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: parentId}, { $set: { children: { 
 childToUpdate } } },
{ fields: { children: 1 }, new: true
})
```

Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Mongoose, if you want to add a new children, you can take advantage of mongoose features

```
Parent.findOne({ _id: parentId}).exec()
.then(parent => {
   return parent.children.push(childToUpdate).save();
});
```