# Push Object with Auto Id in another object (not Array) in NodeJS Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've imported my Database from Firebase so I have few limitations in my schema. as My structure is like this

```
user: {

    ...other nodes

    pictures: { // this is an object, not an array
        autoId: {
            pictureUrl: "",
            pictureNumber: 1
        }
    }
}
```

I want to insert a picture with autoId in my pictures object. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose) and according to this I wrote my code like

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': userId}, {$push:{pictures: {'pictureName': pictureName, 'pictureNumber': pictureNumber}}}, {new: true}, (err, user) => {
       // I am doing something here with user, no need to share
        });
```

but it gives me following error

```
{
    "errorCode": "INTERNAL_ERROR",
    "errorMessage": "The field 'pictures' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: \"00Pag7qQiVbBIOw0zn0k6HWzeo22\"}"
}
```

Can anyone help me how to push object inside another object with autoId in mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var uniqueId = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId();
    uniqueId = uniqueId.toString(); //Convert to string type
    var key = 'pictures.' + uniqueId; // if key is constant we can directly add that.

 User.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': userId}, {$set:{[key]: {'pictureName': pictureName, 'pictureNumber': pictureNumber}}}, {new: true}, (err, user) => {
       // Try using $set instead of $push as $push works on arrays
        });
```

You can find the documentation for the [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and go through it.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't add auto id and overrides my picture object

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry did one edit try that it should add autoId as subObject

Comment: yes you are right, its done, but little modification, because my "autoId" is not constant its a variable, Let me edit your answer.