# how to access each document fields when updating them in mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have a new club created by a user and this user has chosen many users as the members of the club.
so after creating the club I should find all the members and add `club._id` to their `clubs` field. like so

`await User.updateMany({_id : {$in: newClub.members}}, {clubs: [...user.clubs, newClub._id]});`

> Notice! the `user.clubs` is an imaginary variable that I need.

I was wondering if there is a way I can push the new club to their existing clubs without looping over them and pushing `club._id` to their `clubs` field and saving them.
Thanks

> That's right that in this case I aim to use push on an existing document, but my question differs from [Push items into mongo array via mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose) since I generally want to know how to access a field from an existing document when updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MongoDB aggregation pipeline to push the new value to the array

```
User.updateMany(
    {_id : {$in: newClub.members}}, 
    { $push: { clubs: newClub._id } },
    function (error, success) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(success);
        }
    });
);
```