# How to push the object to Mongoose object subarray

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const CampaignSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    liEmail: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: campaignConstants.COMPAIGN_TYPES,
      default: campaignConstants.CUSTOM
    },
    sequences: [
      {
        type: Sequence,
        required: true
      }
    ],
    excludeOption: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    sourceLinks: [String],
    data: [
      {
        targetId: {
          type: ObjectId,
          ref: 'Target'
        },
        profileLink: String,
        name: String,
        headline: String,
        imageurl: String,
        actions: [Activity]
      }
    ],
    browserKey: String
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
  }
)
```

I'm going to push **ACTIVITY** object to the **campaign->data->actions**.
This **ACTIVITY** object will be coming through request with browserKey.
This **browserKey** and **profielLink** is for indicating the **Campaign**. and profileLink to indicate specific object of **data** array

I tried like this myself but not working

```
const campaign = await Campaign.findOne({ browserKey })
const data = campaign.data.filter(
   e => e.profileLink === target.profileLink
)
data.actions.push(action)
await campaign.save()
```

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/mongodb-array-update-operator-$push.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose here is like your case

Comment: Hmm, let me check. Thanks for useful information

Comment: @Егор Лебедев Thanks it's working now. )