# Unable to insert array data into mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

- I am trying to insert data into my mongodb database. I am using mern stack.
- This is my user model for the city data that is in array containing `city_name` & `city_code`

```
city: [{
    city_name: {type: String},
    city_code: {type: String},
  }],
```

- I am passing the values to the register function in this manner

```
city: [{city_name: this.state.c_name, city_code: this.state.c_code}],
```

- This is the function defined to register into the database

```
city: [{ city_name: req.body.c_name, city_code: req.body.c_code}],
```

- No error's message is being returned in the console. I am using a message where if the user is registered successfully it returns `User Registered` or else the error message. But I am not getting anything in the console.
- Constructor defined in the front end side to get the values

```
city: [{city_name: '', city_code: ''}],
```

- **UPDATED**
- This is the function I am using to post the data

```
export const register = newUser => {
  return axios
    .post('users/sign-up', {
      username: newUser.username,
      email: newUser.email,
      phone: newUser.phone,
      dob: newUser.dob,
      city: [{city_name: newUser.c_name, city_code: newUser.c_code}],
      password: newUser.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Registered')
    })
}
```

Comment: You want to push the data into the array. Can you share more of the code you are using to add this data via mongoose? Here is an example of pushing data into an array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose

Comment: I have updated the code. Check that and let me know or else I will update with some more information if needed.

Comment: It has been solved now.

Comment: You should update your code with the solution so that any other people searching for this problem will see how you solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **SOLUTION**
- So whenever you are accessing the data stored in array we need to give the index value.

```
<td>{this.props.obj.city[0].cityname}</td>
<td>{this.props.obj.city[0].citycode}</td>
```