# NodeJs Mongoose Update Category Products

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have Category mongoose document and I want to update his products.Every time on update products just rewrite them and I have only the last put record.How can I populate products?

```
const category = new mongoose.Schema({
  
  products: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" }],
  
});

    module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", category);

    exports.updateCategory = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  let category = await Category.findById(req.params.id);


  category = await Category.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })

  res.send(200).json({
    success: true,
    category
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push items into mongo array via mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose)

Comment: "Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value \"[{\"products\":\"608d588fbf0d1b761cf567cf\"}]\" at path \"products.0\"",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your products are called products in body:

```
category = await Category.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $push: { products: req.body.products } }, {
  new: true,
  runValidators: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
})
```

Comment: Ok with postman I sending this { "products":["kmnkjnjjhu"]} but gives error again.Server started on port 4000 in DEVELOPMENT
Mongo db connected with host: localhost
----------------------------------------
{ products: [ '608d588fbf0d1b761cf567cf' ] }
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: can you update your code in the question?

Comment: I use same code with your example.The products are updated corectly but now  throws this (node:3864) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify   
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status)

Comment: set useFindAndModify to false in your mongoose.connect
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDB', {useFindAndModify: false});`

Comment: Thanks. Also I rewrite res.send with res.satus

Comment: I didn't notice that it was res.send(200) not res.status(200), sorry