# Mongoose - Discord saving channels in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

So I wanna clear it in first that I am a beginner in mongoose. So I wanted a help regarding saving arrays in the database. I want to relate this to Discord. I was building a bot where I want to store the ids of the channels to make the bot respond on them only. Earlier I was using Enmap, but transferred to mongoose for ease. So I don't know how to store arrays then push another string inside that array. Please help me out in this situation

Comment: What have you tried already? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. This seems like the kind of question that can be googled.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose) its so common question, even if its not solve the proble search stackoverflow again you will find what you need, also mongodb documentation is so good, dont know about mongoose docs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just so easy, after creating your model aka schema, you just set the type to array

*example:*

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
   GuildId: {
     type: String
     required: true
   },

   ChannelIds: {
      type: Array,
      default: []
   }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("the_model_name", schema)
```

Alright now in your command you will need to get the data from the db

*example:*

```js
// first you will need to define your schema
const schema = require('schema path')

// now we will define data and we will use try catch to not get any errors
let data;
try {
   // Put here the guild id such as the message.guild.id, or anything that is unique for that data
   data = await schema.findOne({ GuildId: ## })

   // if there is no data we want to create a schema for it
   if(!data) {
      data = await schema.create({ GuildId: ## })
   }
} catch(e) {
   // if there is any error log it
   console.log(e)
}
```

Now after we got the data we just push the channel id, to add it you just need to push it.

*example*

```js
data.ChannelIds.push(/*the channel id or whatever you want to push*/)
```

last but not least just save the data

*example*

```js
await data.save()
```

Comment: @Felix you can accept the answer if it helped you :D

Comment: @I_love_vegetables he prolly asked and never checked back :(

Comment: yeah.. its fine, i gave you a +1 :D

Comment: @I_love_vegetables Appreciated!

Comment: @UltraX same here ~