# How can I iterate an array of (Mongoose) objects and output string properties?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I have this Handlebar code in an Express project:

```
{{#if user}}
<p>Welcome, <a href="/profile/{{user.[_id]}}">{{user.username}}</a>.</p>
{{#each user.snippets}}
{{log 'heading' this.heading}}
<h1>{{heading}}</h1>
<code>{{code}}</code>
{{/each}}
```

The username is output correctly, and the loop is executed the right amount of times (which I see from the logging). However, the string properties **heading** and **code** are undefined, even though they are correctly set in my database. Both **user** and **snippets** are Mongoose objects or schemas (I am not sure about the terminology), or rather snippets (a property of users) is an array of such objects.

I am not a 100% sure if I'm using the **this** keyword correctly, or if I need brackets. I have also tried helpers, but they don't seem to do what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would be curious to know what each `snippet` object looks like. I would try `{{log this}}` within the `{{#each user.snippets}}` to make sure each `snippet` object has the shape you expect.

Comment: @76484 Oh, good idea. I haven't used the logger as much as in Javascript, I'm afraid. In fact, I only used the line shown in the code above.

Logging the snippet object gives me 'new ObjectId("[hexadecimal string]")'. I know this is the _id of Mongoose objects. I tried logging user, which shows a more natural object.

I checked the database (I use MongoDB Atlas, for reference), and it does seem as if the snippets property of users is, indeed, an array of those ObjectIds. This is probably a fault with my JS code. I probably don't initialise each array index correctly.

Comment: @76484 Yeah, I have probably pushed the snippet object to the snippets array wrong. Like this: user.snippets.push(snippet).

You wouldn't by any chance know how to correctly do it. I am trying to do it like user.updateOne({ $push: {snippets: snippet} }), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049923/3397771

Comment: @76484 Thanks, but I asked a new question, where the problem is more specified.