# Updating a Subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a database for my Giveaway Bot. It consist of 2 collections, `Main` (holding settings) and `Giveaway` which is nested in under the `Main` collection. I can create my giveaway's without problems. However I want to add some data later on using findOneAndUpdate.

Running the code below I always get this error: `Updating the path 'giveaways.duration' would create a conflict at 'giveaways'`. Can anyone help solving this issue ?

schema.js

```
const giveawaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    _id: String,
    destination: String,
    duration: String,
    winners: String,
    price: String,
})

const mainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    log_channel_id: String,
    admin_roles: [],
    giveaways: [giveawaySchema],

const Main = mongoose.model("mainSchema", mainSchema);
const Giveaway = mongoose.model("giveawaySchema", giveawaySchema);

module.exports = { Main, Giveaway }
});
```

Part of my code used for updating:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const {Main, Giveaway} = require("../models/schema.js")

const newestGiveaway = await Main.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: guildId,
        'giveaways._id': giveaway_id,
    },  
    {   
        "$set":{
            "giveaways.duration": "3d",
            "giveaways.winners": "20",
            "giveaways.price": "Price to Win",
         },
    },
    {
        upsert: true,
    }
```

Thank you for your help :)

A small side question. I have fetched the Main document (the parent) before already can I make my search cheaper/ more efficent by only searching through this instead of running the findOneandUpdate method on the whole database ?

**Edit 1:**

I found that it is neccesary to use the $ operator and have updated my code. However I still get the same error:

```
{
   $set:{
      "giveaways.$.duration": "3d",
      "giveaways.$.winners": "20,
      "giveaways.$.price": "Price to Win",
   },
},
```

**Edit 2:**

Just to clarify, the creation and nesting of the giveawaySchemas works but I am not able to update the nested document by using the code above.
My child component is already created by using the code below. I now want to update this child (`newGiveaway` with `_id` of 1)

```
const currentGuild = await Main.findOne({_id: guildId})

const newGiveaway = await Giveaway.create({
    _id: 1,
    destination: 12345678,
});

currentGuild.giveaways.push(newGiveaway)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your schema declaration to use a `ref` to the `giveawaySchema`:

```
const giveawaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    _id: String,
    destination: String,
    duration: String,
    winners: String,
    price: String,
})

const mainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    log_channel_id: String,
    admin_roles: [],
    giveaways: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'giveawaySchema'
    }],

const Main = mongoose.model("mainSchema", mainSchema);
const Giveaway = mongoose.model("giveawaySchema", giveawaySchema);

module.exports = { Main, Giveaway }
```

Then, you will just need to update your giveaways directy:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Giveaway } = require('../models/schema.js');

const newestGiveaway = await Main.findByIdAndUpdate(
  giveaway_id,
  {
    duration: '3d',
    winners: '20',
    price: 'Price to Win',
  },
  {
    new: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `mainSchema` you define giveaways field as an array of `giveawaySchema` object. So, you have to treat it as an array, not an object. If you want to treat it as an object, you will have to update `mainSchema` by removing square bracket at `giveawaysSchema`.

[Relevant Question for how to pushing item into mongo array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049707/push-items-into-mongo-array-via-mongoose)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I knew that I need to push my giveawaySchema into mainSchema using .push. However my giveawaySchema is already created before using this code: `currentGuild.giveaways.push(newGiveaway)`. This works perfectly but I now want to update this giveaway by adding more data like the duration. I dont want to create a new giveawaySchema. In the link provided they create a new children schema but don't say how to find and update an existing child schema